# Android: how to do a checkbox list from installed user apps

Tags: android, list, checkbox

i'm very new to android development...
i'm still on leaning phase...

and it seems like a very big forest for me...

there's is something specific i want to make...

i want to create an app that will list(checkbox) all the installed user apps...

and i want each app will appear with the logo on the left side of the app name... and the checkbox will be on right and the list will extend vertically...

so the User can check any app on the list...

but I certainly don't know where to start Y_Y

Answer (score 0):

First read about PackageManager.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledApplications%28int%29

This will give you a list of installed android apps.